# Access innerXML with and without node attributes

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Given these two node variations

```
<Path>C:\OneA.txt</Path>
```

and

```
<Path force="True">C:\OneB.txt</Path>
```

and a variable that contains the parent node and children, I am having problems finding a single solution to get at the inner text.

In the first condition, `$variable.path` returns the inner text *C:\OneA.txt*.

But in the second condition this doesn't work, it returns a [System.Xml.XmlElement]. 
I CAN use $variable.path.force and it returns true, but I need to use `$variable.path.'#text'` or `$variable.path.InnerXml` to get back *C:\OneB.txt*.

But if I use either of those techniques in the first condition it returns nothing at all. Is there some single approach that would work in both conditions, or is my only option to see if the node has attributes, and if so use the one approach, and if not use the other? I had hoped to not need to assign this to a new variable, but without a single approach for both conditions that becomes the path to minimal conditionals.

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Why? The OP asked a simple, answerable question about a programming problem and provided a rather clear, straightforward description of the problem they're experiencing.

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers He mentions variable and conditions that do not appear on the post so it fails to comply with stackoverflow's MCVE principle (Minimum, complete and verifiable example).

Comment: I did not have any problem verifying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using dot-access on a node that contains just a text node (no attributes, no nested nodes), PowerShell automatically expands the value of that text node. However, in your second example the node also has an attribute, so that automatic expansion doesn't happen.

I'd recommend avoiding dot-access and instead using the `SelectSingleNode()` method with an [XPath expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx), so that you always get a node object:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode('//Path').'#text'
```

Note, however, that XPath expressions are case sensitive, so an expression `//path` would not match a node `<Path>`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense that PS is doing some stuff behind the scenes that I wasn't aware of. And it sounds like I will need to assign this to a variable, since I won't really want to use SelectSingleNode 20 times where this data is used.